# Errors in Minimal.launch after installing Fuerte Turtlebot Upgrade

Tags: turtlebot, roslib, ros-fuerte, turtlebot-apps, android-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu Oneiric, following upgrade instructions to Fuerte Turtlebot, http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/fuerte/Robot_Upgrade, roscore started Ok  with "minimal.launch" though with several ROS error msgs in addition to a Lenovo x120e "battery" issue I reported in an earlier post:

core service [/rosout] found
process[appmaster-1]: started with pid [14537]
process[app_manager-2]: started with pid [14538]
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [14539]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-4]: started with pid [14541]
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [14543]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-6]: started with pid [14548]

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py:54: UserWarning: roslib.rosenv is deprecated, please use rospkg or rosgraph.rosenv
import roslib.rosenv

[ WARN] [1336438418.625508278]: The root link base_footprint has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.

process[robot_pose_ekf-7]: started with pid [14581]

turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]

[WARN] [WallTime: 1336438419.701618] Unable to check laptop battery info. Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info'
[WARN] [WallTime: 1336438419.702619] Unable to check laptop battery state. Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state'

ERROR: Cannot locate app file for turtlebot_teleop/android_teleop: package is not installed.

[INFO] [WallTime: 1336438419.739866] Starting app manager for turtlebot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py", line 68, in 
import turtlebot_node.robot_types as robot_types

File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/robot_types.py", line 29, in 
import create_sensor_handler

File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/create_sensor_handler.py", line 42, in 
_struct_I = roslib.message.struct_I

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'struct_I'

[INFO] [WallTime: 1336438419.766782] Waiting for foreign master [http://localhost:11312] to come up...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1336438419.772081] Foreign master is available

[INFO] [WallTime: 1336438419.809062] Registering (/turtlebot/app_list,http://10.0.1.6:60690/) on master http://localhost:11312

[INFO] [WallTime: 1336438419.821318] Registering (/turtlebot/application/app_status,http://10.0.1.6:60690/) on master http://localhost:11312
turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]

Suggestions to troubleshoot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33494/errors-in-minimal.launch-after-installing-fuerte-turtlebot-upgrade/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreasB](https://answers.ros.org/users/1802/andreasb/) on 2012-05-08**:
I'm seeing similar problems after updating to Fuerte and at the same time updating to ubuntu precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This it is a defect (see ticket for patch or better wait till its merged into the trunk):

https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/139

p.s.: the fixes I applied:

```
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: rostest
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

-> add /opt/ros/fuerte/share to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/create_sensor_handler.py", line 42, in <module>
    _struct_I = roslib.message.struct_I
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'struct_I'
```

-> get fix from https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/139
in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot execute sudo patch -p1 < PathToDiffFix

I also applied https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/137 to fix the install.bash and https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/142 to fix kinect.launch

For turtlebot.eu fellows: Read
http://answers.ros.org/question/27755/roomba-500-series-installation-problem

You have to change the turtlebot_node parameters robot_type publish_tf has_gyro

---

Originally posted by [ZendelO](https://answers.ros.org/users/2355/zendelo/) with karma: 16 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20100806.155025.c730c454.en.html

suggests this might have to do with your python path (same struct_I issue).
You could try
echo $PYTHONPATH
and see if there are old references to electric in there

---

Originally posted by [pallegro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1891/pallegro/) with karma: 36 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1